# Get the RGBA value of layout items that only appear at runtime and are not accessible through code

Tags: ios

How do you get the RGBA values of layout items that are not visible in the interface builder and are not set by code?

Like alert views or the delete button of a UITableview.

At the moment I am looking for the RGBA value of the red color of a tableview delete button?

Since I like the color I would change my other red stuff to that color.
It is not the standard UIColor.redColor()

Comment: You should have an app on your mac called Digital Color meter that you can use to get this information.

Comment: Don't be so quick to assume you can't change the color of the delete button. As of iOS 8, it's easy with [UITableViewRowAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewRowAction_class/index.html).

Comment: just assumed because off all the unanswered questions on SO about changing it... But that is awesome! Then I can get the color I really want :) thx

Comment: I don't understand the qns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- As 8-bit RGB: 255, 59, 48
- As UIColor RGB: 1.0, 0.23, 0.19
- As hex: 0xFF3B30

Answer (score -2):

Why not just what's already available ?

Match any item to it by :

```
matchedItem.color = [UIColor redColor];
```

But you know there is this cool little feature in Xcode if you press <kbd>option</kbd>+click over code then a popup will appear with it's declarations, types, returns, descriptions etc. And this is what redColor displays :

[image: pic1]

Furthermore, this what happens when you click on the UIColor.h hyperlink:

[image: pic2]

**So it gives all the values to you. For example, RED Colors RGB value is 1.0, 0.0, 0.0. So in other words a 1.0 value in RGB is 255, naturally. So the RGB value is (255, 0, 0)**

And voila

Comment: how will this reveal the red delete button? There is no piece of code describing the slide out. So nothing to option click on....

Comment: @RMenke so is your question How to Reveal the red delete button, or is it what you titled it..what is the red color of a tableview delete button? I answered the latter since thats what you implied of asking

Comment: @RMenke the red delete buttons use `[UIColor redColor]` i was simply showing you how to obtain that color reference

Comment: I meant, like I said, the red color of the delete button. Not what is the color of UIColor.redColor.

Comment: it doesn't use UIColor.redColor, look at the answer of keithbhunter

Comment: So what does it use? Destructive and redColor are synonymous @RMenke

Comment: well now your just being picky - but glad you got it suited to your needs

Comment: @soulshined FYI, [UIColor redColor] and the destructive button color are two completely different colors (although both are shades of red).

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov yeah. Oldie but goodie. Didn't care to delete the answer because I wanted to show the SO community it's ok to be wrong sometimes